# Clipping UIView to a circle using CGContextClip

Tags: objective-c, cgcontext

I've looked through various similar questions and still can't seem to get my code to work.  I have a UIView with an image drawn to it (`[image drawInRect:bounds]`), but I'm missing something in my context clipping:

```
// Get context & bounds, and calculate centre & radius
CGContextRef ctx=UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGRect bounds=[self bounds];
CGPoint centre;
centre.x=bounds.origin.x+0.5*bounds.size.width;
centre.y=bounds.origin.y+0.5*bounds.size.height;
CGFloat radius=centre.x;

// Draw image
UIImage *backImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"backimage.png"];
[backImage drawInRect:bounds];

// Create clipping path and clip context
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddArc(path, NULL, centre.x, centre.y, radius, 0, 2*M_PI, 0);
CGContextAddPath(ctx, path);
CGContextClip(ctx);
```

Any ideas of where I went wrong?  Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`radius=centre.x` seems to be wrong. The radius should be half the width or height:

```
CGFloat radius = 0.5*bounds.size.width;
```

You could also use the convenience function

```
CGPathRef path = CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(bounds, NULL);
```

**UPDATE:** It turned out that the actual problem was that the clipping path was modified *after* drawing the image.

The clipping path is used for all future drawing operations and must therefore be set *before* the drawing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I tried this code, but unfortunately it's still not working.  (My width and height are 114, and my centre coordinates and radius are all 57.)

Comment: @Rogare: Do you draw the image before of after the clipping? What does the output look like, and what output do you expect?

Comment: I draw the image beforehand.  It looks like a white square with a hat in it, though I'd like it to be a white circle with a hat in it.  (The background behind this image has a pattern.)

Comment: @Rogare: I think you have to clip first and draw the image after that.

Comment: (I've just updated my code to include the image-drawing lines.  Now it shows the entirety of my drawRect method.)

Comment: @Rogare: You are welcome, and thanks for accepting. I will update the answer accordingly.